# How to handle floating point error in line segment contains point algorithm

Tags: floating-point, precision, computational-geometry

I am working on some geometric algorithms and I've been struggling for a while with floating point error mitigation.

More specifically, I have written a method for checking whether a line segment contains a point by comparing the sum of the distance of this point to the two endpoints of the segment with the length of the line segment.

I am currently using a fixed epsilon value, but it seems to be returning invalid outputs when the point is too close to the endpoints or when the line segment is too long.

Sample code in Java below:

```
public boolean lineSegmentContainsPoint(Vec3D line, Vec3D point) {
        final float eps = 0.001f;
        final float lineLength = line.startPt.distanceTo(line.endPt);
        final float distanceToStart = point.distanceTo(line.startPt);
        final float distanceToEnd = point.distanceTo(line.endPt);
        return Math.abs(lineLength - (distanceToStart + distanceToEnd)) < eps;
    }
```

I understand that the issue is caused due to accumulative floating point errors, but it's not really clear how I could tackle it. I tried using double instead of float, but it didn't really help in the above mentioned edge cases. Any suggestions or help would be really appreciated!

Comment: What do you call "invalid outputs" ? How do you check them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The locus of the points such that

```
D0 + D1 - L < ε
```

(by the triangular inequality, no need to take the absolute value) is the inside of an ellipse with long axis

```
L + ε/2
```

and short axis

```
√(2Lε + ε²).
```

It may contain points that you don't expect. I wouldn't rate this test as a good for "line segment insideness". I doubt that your problem has anything to do with floating-point inaccuracy.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I added a condition to check whether the 3 points are colinear. I think now it should work without any issues.

Comment: @leonidasarch: What do you call "invalid outputs" ? How do you check them ?

Comment: By writing unit tests. eg. A line from (0,0,0) to (1000000,0,0) and a point with coordinates (1,0.1,0) would return true with the method I wrote above.

Comment: @leonidasarch: indeed, the short axis is 36 units. Thanks for the info.